# iPhone quick mute/unmute while in a call for the visually impaired

Tags: iphone, audio, facetime, accessibility, call

I have a visually impaired friend with an iPhone SE 3rd edition.  He is unable to find the mute/unmute button while on a cellular or FaceTime audio phone call.  Is there a shortcut or an easy way to do this built-in?  Or perhaps there a way to map a gesture or physical button to this?  He's been using numerous other accessible features on iPhones for 10+ years, and is super efficient with it.  However, this one feature is either missing or hard for myself and him to find.